# Calculating similarity of sets of variable length

Tags: machine-learning

If I have two sets, i can calculate similarity coefficient of them using Jaccard index. Is there algorithm i can calculate similarity with variable number of entities? For example, let's say we have first pair of sets:

`{A1,B1,C1}` and `{A1,B2,C1,D1}`

`{A1,B1,C1}` and `{A1,B3,C4,D5}`

I can say that first pair is more similar, but how to calculate it mathematically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) $\displaystyle J(A,B) = {{|A \cap B|}\over{|A \cup B|}} = {{|A \cap B|}\over{|A| + |B| - |A \cap B|}}$ seems to handle differently sized sets as part of its definition

In your examples it would give $\dfrac25$ and $\dfrac16$ and the first value is certainly higher than the second

Comment: Oh, ok, i just wanted to be safe I can use Jaccard index for variable sized sets. Thanks.